# bind_rows with a large number of tibbles

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large number of tibbles that I'd like to combine into a single tibble using the bind_rows command from dplyr. All tibbles have the same column headers.  I want to avoid having to type out the names of all the tibbles in the command.  There is an obvious pattern to the naming convention of these tibbles.  Here's the long-hand version:

```
all <- distinct(bind_rows(
          level1_1, level1_2, level1_3, level1_4, level1_5, level1_6, level1_7, level1_8,
          level2_2, level2_3, level2_4, level2_5, level2_6, level2_7, level2_8,
          level3_3, level3_4, level3_5, level3_6, level3_7, level3_8,
          level4_4, level4_5, level4_6, level4_7, level4_8,
          level5_5, level5_6, level5_7, level5_8,
          level6_6, level6_7, level6_8,
          level7_7, level7_8,
          level8_8))
```

I wonder if there's a more compact way of writing this command?

Comment: How/why did you create to many separate tibbles? Normally you would read such values into named lists rather than create a bunch of separate loose variables in your global environment with index values hard coded in their name. Chances are there are more R-like ways to do things if you take a step back first.

Comment: @MrFlick I did, in fact, "take a step back" for a few hours yesterday in an unsuccessful effort to produce this output in list form.  I've posted this particular problem up at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65794638/loop-output-stored-as-list.  

What do you mean by "R-like"? As I'm aware, R is open-source and not subject to any particular person's set of values.  If what you mean is "coded more efficiently" then I agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can get the values of objects into a `list` with `mget` from the string object names returned with `ls` by specifying the `pattern`

```
library(dplyr)
out <- distinct(bind_rows(mget(ls(pattern = '^level\\d+_\\d+$'))))
```

The `pattern` suggests to check for objects in the global environment that starts (`^`) with 'level', followed by one or more digits (`\\d+`), then an underscore and one or more digits (`_\\d+`) till the end (`$`) of the string

---

If there are other objects of similar pattern and want to constrain it with specific object names, create the combinations with `expand.grid` and `paste`

```
nm1 <- with(subset(expand.grid(1:8, 1:8), Var1 >= Var2), 
        paste0("level", Var2, "_", Var1))
distinct(bind_rows(mget(nm1)))
```

Comment: While this is the correct approach to deal with the problem *as described*, it it's important to note that that whatever code generated those separate objects should have instead stored them as elements of a list object. Then the solution simply becomes dplyr::rbind_list(.) or data.table::rbindlist(.) or do.call(rbind, .).

Comment: @Michael `bind_rows` from `dplyr` succeeds the `rbind_list`.  I agree that it can be stored as list  and creating multiple objects in the global env is not recommended

Comment: @Michael I agree with your first comment *as described*.  I've posted that particular problem at stackoverflow.com/questions/65794638/loop-output-stored-as-list.