# Loop Output Stored as List

Tags: r, list, loops

I have wide supervisory data where a single observation consists of a level 1 employee and their department all the way down to level 8.  I use a loop with other commands to produce a list all employees and the departments beneath them in long format so that I can see what departments employees are responsible for at all levels.  There may be a more elegant way to do this than a loop, but it works fine.  Sample data (through level 3 for succinctness):

```
data <- tibble(LV1_Employee_Name = "Chuck", LV1_Employee_Nbr = "1", LV1_Department = "Tha Boss", LV1_Department_Nbr = "90",
               LV2_Employee_Name = c("Alex", "Alex", "Paul", "Paul", "Jennifer", "Jennifer"), LV2_Employee_Nbr = c("2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4"), LV2_Department = c("Leadership", "Leadership", "Finance", "Finance", "Philanthropy", "Philanthropy"), LV2_Department_Nbr = c("91", "91", "92", "92",  "93", "93"),
               LV3_Employee_Name = c("Dan", "Wendy", "Sarah", "Monique", "Miguel", "Brandon"), LV3_Employee_Nbr = c("2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4"), LV3_Department = c("Analytics", "Pop Health", "Acounting", "Investments", "Yacht Aquisitions", "Golf Junkets"), LV3_Department_Nbr = c("94", "95", "96", "97",  "98", "99"))
```

The loop below first produces six tibbles named level1_1, level1_2, level1_3, level2_2, level2_3, level3_3.  Each tibble contains an employee name, number, and the department at the same department level or below. The code then lists and binds the rows of these tibbles with `ls()` and `bind_rows()`, then applies the `distinct()` command, and I've got what I need.

```
first_department <- 1

data_colnames <- c("Employee", "Employee_Id", "Department", "Department_Number")

for(i in 1:3){
  for(k in first_department:3){
    
    assign(paste0("level", i, "_", k), setNames(distinct(as_tibble(c(data[ ,paste0("LV", i, "_", "Employee_Name")], data[ ,paste0("LV", i, "_", "Employee_Nbr")],
                                                                     data[ ,paste0("LV", k, "_", "Department")],  data[ ,paste0("LV", k, "_", "Department_Nbr")]))), 
                                                data_colnames))
    
  }
  first_department = first_department + 1
}

employees_departments <- distinct(bind_rows(mget(ls(pattern = "^level")))) %>%
  filter(is.na(Department) == FALSE)

rm(list = ls(pattern = "^level"))
```

What I'd like to do is, rather than produce an initial output of six tibbles, have the loop itself output the list.  This will save me from having a huge list of tibbles in the output which, I'm told, is not very "R-like".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a revised version that stores the results in a list within your loop. This will include an index `idx` incremented each time through the loop. Afterwards, you can use `bind_rows` on this list to get a complete result.

```
library(tidyverse)

idx <- 1
first_department <- 1
data_colnames <- c("Employee", "Employee_Id", "Department", "Department_Number")
data_lst <- list()

for(i in 1:3){
  for(k in first_department:3){
    data_lst[[idx]] <- setNames(
      distinct(as_tibble(
        c(data[ ,paste0("LV", i, "_", "Employee_Name")], 
          data[ ,paste0("LV", i, "_", "Employee_Nbr")],
          data[ ,paste0("LV", k, "_", "Department")],  
          data[ ,paste0("LV", k, "_", "Department_Nbr")]))),
      data_colnames)
    idx <- idx + 1
  }
  first_department = first_department + 1
}

distinct(bind_rows(data_lst)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Department))
```

**Output**

```
   Employee Employee_Id Department        Department_Number
   <chr>    <chr>       <chr>             <chr>            
 1 Chuck    1           Tha Boss          90               
 2 Chuck    1           Leadership        91               
 3 Chuck    1           Finance           92               
 4 Chuck    1           Philanthropy      93               
 5 Chuck    1           Analytics         94               
 6 Chuck    1           Pop Health        95               
 7 Chuck    1           Acounting         96               
 8 Chuck    1           Investments       97               
 9 Chuck    1           Yacht Aquisitions 98               
10 Chuck    1           Golf Junkets      99               
11 Alex     2           Leadership        91               
12 Paul     3           Finance           92               
13 Jennifer 4           Philanthropy      93               
14 Alex     2           Analytics         94               
15 Alex     2           Pop Health        95               
16 Paul     3           Acounting         96               
17 Paul     3           Investments       97               
18 Jennifer 4           Yacht Aquisitions 98               
19 Jennifer 4           Golf Junkets      99               
20 Dan      2           Analytics         94               
21 Wendy    2           Pop Health        95               
22 Sarah    3           Acounting         96               
23 Monique  3           Investments       97               
24 Miguel   4           Yacht Aquisitions 98               
25 Brandon  4           Golf Junkets      99
```

Comment: Interesting solution!  What's happening with the full data, unfortunately, is that the `pivot_longer()` step creates a tibble of 35,232 observations.  When I then proceed to the `fuzzy_left_join()` step, R processes the command for a bit, then outputs "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.6Gb"  

I'm curious about what the `pivot_longer()` command is doing;  how it selects the level number, knows to put this number in a new column called "level," then gives the resulting columns a generic name.  I didn't think I could use pivot  when I originally started this problem.

Comment: `pivot_longer` "lengthens" the data (increasing rows, decreasing columns)...take a look at what `data_long` looks like, and you'll see each row includes: (1) row number (since same row implies relationship with other departments), (2) level, (3) Employee name and ID, and (4) Department and Department Number. While the original data had 3 names and 3 departments on each row, the long version only has a single name and dept. each row.

Comment: `pivot_longer` takes a `names_pattern` which uses regex (regular expression) to define what the key/value should be...in this case, it separates the number `\\d+` in one column, which is the level, and the word `\\w+` in another column, which is one of the 4 (Employee_Name, Employee_Nbr, Department, Department_Nbr). This is determine by interpreting the original column names...

Comment: Please see edited version. I added a similar approach, but doing small joins based on row number of original data frame. This should give the same answer but work better with larger data. Please let me know if this works. If your data is huge, could also consider a `data.table` solution and non-equi join.

Comment: Data is 4,404 obs of 32 variables (8 levels).  4,613 employees and 281 departments.  I've used `pivot_longer` before, but never with the pattern option using a regex, so it was nice to see this in action.  In the regex, do the values in () signify the values to be split out into columns?  Interested in whether this can be done without a loop, although the loop does process quite quickly - it's just that I can't get it to output as a list.

Comment: Yes - in regex those are the groups to be extracted. One is a number (level number such as 1 is "LV1_...") and the other a word (such as "Employee_Nbr" that comes after the underscore). Did you try my alternative solution? Instead of a loop, you can also use `apply` or `map` from purrr...and in my example I created a list where rows are combined in the end. Let me know what you think...

Comment: The alternative solution works after adding `filter(is.na(Department) == FALSE)` at the end of  `bind_rows`.  This wasn't shown in the toy data, but there are many rows of data where there isn't a lower level employee.  The processing time on the loop command in the alt. solution takes about 2.5 minutes, however.  In the original code I posted, the loop takes a hot second since all it does is pull out 36 chunks of data and bind the rows together.  Crude, but fast.  The problem is that since I use `assign` to name these chunks, I don't know how to pre-assign the output to a single list.

Comment: Please see revised answer - this will put results in a list. Is this what you were looking for? Sorry about my confusion.